# WatiN: The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, service, watin

I am calling WatiN from a C# windows service. When I invoke WatiN it throws the following exception. The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer

I have tried starting up a thread and setting the apartment state via

```
mythread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
```

but that resulted in another error

***Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.***

I also tried adding an attribute to the Service entry point.

```
static class Program
{
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
          ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the second (bold) error. Can you show some more code? I had a similar requirement and creating a new thread, setting the ApartmentState and calling .Start() followed by .Join() - essentially doing only the STA bound stuff in there - worked fine for me.

Comment: To further clarify. I created a thread within my service and SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) that invokes my WATiN code. 
That threw the following exception.

Comment: Hi Benjamin! Indeed you are correct! I wasnt joining my thread. You should have posted as the answer ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know Benjamin's already posted a 'working' answer, but I thought I'd add a couple of things I've experienced when I've got this error when trying to execute WatiN tests:
For NUnit, you should add something like this to your app.config for the tests:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- WatiN can only host IE in STA mode -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA"/>
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
```

In MbUnit, modify your TestFixture attribute like this:

```
[TestFixture(ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA)]
```

HTH,
Pete.

Ha - it's actually in the documentation. Doh!
http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/

Comment: This is the most helpful answer when you just want to get WatiN with IE to work in your test project. Thanks, Pete!

Comment: for NUnit 2.5 and up this did not work for me, this answer worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5293312/173817

Comment: http://watin.org/ Link is dead

Comment: found a tut https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/27c648/automated-ui-test-with-watin-and-specflow-in-net-part-1777/

Answer (score 9):

That's not an error, it is just a diagnostic from the debugger.  It is telling you that it can't give you debug info on whatever you put in the watch window.  That's common with code that is compiled in the Release configuration, the JIT compiler optimizes the machine code and commonly puts local variables in CPU registers.  Making their value unavailable to the debugger, it isn't smart enough to figure out what register was used.  It occasionally happens in the Debug release as well when there's unmanaged code on the call stack.  Which is not uncommon for WebBrowser, there's a very large chunk of unmanaged code that makes it work.

FWIW, just switching the thread's apartment state to STA is not enough.  The thread must also pump a Windows message loop to make a single-threaded apartment operate properly.  If you don't, you'll see that operations on STA objects like WebBrowser will deadlock.  For example, you'll never get the DocumentCompleted event when you navigate to a site.  Running a message loop requires calling Application.Run() or Form.ShowDialog() in a WF app.

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense!

Comment: Thanks very much. Joining the thread helped resolve the issue!

Answer (score 3):

The attribute that I used to get over seeing this error is:
    [TestFixture, RequiresSTA]

As per adrianbanks answer on: [How to run unit tests in STAThread mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434067/how-to-run-unit-tests-in-stathread-mode)