# Copy paste excel data into Rich text box + remove grid lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to copy data from an excel sheet into a a rich text box in a Winform .NET project.

Right now there are grid lines are coming up in the rich text box. How do I eliminate the grid lines from the rich text box.

Because I do not want to show the grid lines in the rich text box.

Please help me

Thanks Sandeep

Comment: Does it have to be a Rich Text Box? Could you just use a regular TextBox?

Comment: can i eliminate the grid lines after they are pasted into the richtext box?

Comment: could a richtext box be converted to ordinary text box on the fly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this in the keydown event of you richtextbox (if you are using the normal paste method)

```
        private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                string st = Clipboard.GetText();
                richTextBox1.Text = st;
            }
        }
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Banged my head against wall with this one. I was testing the different methods available on the Clipboard class with nUnit and every method returned null. With nUnit, you must add the `[RequiresSTA]` attribute to the class.

Final result would look like `[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293312/1444511

Comment: This seems unrelated to the posted RichTextBox problem.