# Unable to set WinForms clipboard in unit test

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit, clipboard, sta

I'd like to populate the Forms.Clipboard with text from a NUnit test.

The first problem I encountered was that the Clipboard must be used in STA mode. I found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434067/how-to-run-unit-tests-in-stathread-mode) (NUnit 2.5.x+) to set the RequiresSTA attribute on the method.

Next I get an ExternalException when calling Clipboard.SetText(). I found [the solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/a23c31df-e645-4500-ab4a-e6178510a9b1) to use Clipboard.SetDataObject(object, bool, int, int) where you can specify retryTimes to make several attempts to set the clipboard. This hacky solution works *sometimes*, which obviously isn't good enough (increasing the retryTimes parameter will of course also increase the chance of succeeding).

Others (for instance [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434067/how-to-run-unit-tests-in-stathread-mode)) have succeeded with this, so perhaps it has something to do with my environment: I run VS2010 under Windows 7 64-bit targeting .NET 3.5 and x86. The NUnit version is 2.5.9.

I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a unit test.  Have you considered abstracting away from the windows clipboard and using your own "IClipboard" interface while in unit test?

Comment: It is an environmental problem, another process is messing with the clipboard.  Use taskmgr.exe and start killing processes until you find the troublemaker.  Hopefully that one isn't your own.

Comment: @agent-j: Couldn't agree more. In this case however Clipboard is part of what I'm testing :(

Comment: @Hans Passant: Good thinking. After killing a few apps it seems to be working. I'll do some more testing a report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

As suggested by Hans Passant in the comments, the problem was that another process was interfering. The evil process seems to be Google Chrome.