# Calling CreateInstance causes thread error

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've created small portable library [(reference](https://miniautfac.codeplex.com/), targeting: Windows, Windows 8, Windows Phone 7.5) for educational purposes. I've decided to use it in my small Windows 8 Metro style app. Unfortunately, when I call method from the library the exception is thrown:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

at the following line:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(outputType, constructorArguments.ToArray());
```

([Resolve method](https://miniautfac.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/20242#563105))
The **outputType** is a **typeof(ClassFromMyMetroStyleApp)**.
Library is added to project as dll reference.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Edit:
 Method is call from UnitTest in Metro Style App solution:

```
[TestClass]
public class ResolvingTypesTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The school context interface test.
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void SchoolContextTest()
    {
        var schoolContext = TypeService.Services.Resolve<ISchoolContext>();

        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(SchoolCollection), schoolContext.GetType());
    }
}
```

where **TypeService** is static class, and **Services** is static property of IResolvable type (interface is provided by Library).

Services property:

```
/// <summary>
    /// The resolvable.
    /// </summary>
    private static IResolvable resolvable;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type services.
    /// </summary>
    public static IResolvable Services
    {
        get
        {
            if (resolvable == null)
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.Register();
                resolvable = builder.Build();
            }

            return resolvable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ClassFromMyMetroStyleApp` a UI class?  And what are `constructorArguments`?

Comment: This is a COM marshaling error, heavily used in Store apps.  The cause is unclear but very high odds that you'll need to tell your test runner to initialize the thread that runs the test properly.  Here is a [sample question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434067/how-to-run-unit-tests-in-stathread-mode) that discusses the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution (thanks to Hans Passant for clue!)
Need to add an attribute to the test method:

```
[UITestMethod]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error in a Single-Threaded Apartment when you use certain objects (usually UI objects) in one thread that was created in another thread.

Comment: ClassFromMyMetroStyleApp is simple class that implements ISchoolProvider only (and has no base type). constructorArguments is a array of instances of ClassFromMyMetroStyleApp parameters. In this case that array is empty (ClassFromMy.. has parameterless constructor).

Comment: sorry, i meant ISchoolContext, not ISchoolProvider :-)

Answer (score -1):

No only because of cross thread access but also performance reasons, Activator is discouraged to use.
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/04/02/don-t-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions.aspx

Here author has provided a comparison between Activator and using Lambda expression to instantiate the object. 
I wrapped the code in a single method for u. Try this

```
public object CreateObject(Type type)
    {

        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[]{});
        // Make a NewExpression that calls the ctor with the args we just created
        NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(ctor, null);

        // Create a lambda with the New expression as body and our param object[] as arg
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(newExp, null);

        // Compile it
        var compiled = lambda.Compile();
        if (compiled != null)
        {
        }
        return compiled.DynamicInvoke();
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure how this applies to the question.  Your reference doesn't detail how this would avoid a cross-thread exception, plus it applies to compiled expressions--which isn't what the OP is using.

Comment: downvote? I just proposed an altenative way to instantiate object which is better than activator and does not produce cross thread exceptions

Comment: i think it's worth a try. I'll check it later (5-6hrs,I'm out of home right now).

Comment: Unfortunately, code is not working - LambdaExpression has no Compile() method.

Comment: I turned out, that Portable Class Library does not support Compile Method. There is no FormatterServices. Need to use CreateInstance and get rid of error.

Comment: Ok, I know what was wrong. In the constructor of ClassFromMyMetroStyleApp I've been creating new BitmapSource instance. It caused thread error.

Comment: Marked as answer - lambda expression method helped me to find the cause. One question - how can I provide instances of construtor parameteres in your wrapped method?

Comment: Need to modify the code a little. I'll update the modified method soon.